# Filter files with patterns

Tags: r, regex

I want to read several files from a directory where there are a lot of files. I found the first filter relatively quickly, so that only certain files are still displayed.

```
dir(
  path = "m:/"
  ,pattern = "bestand|bewegung\.dat|txt$"
)
```

As result I get the following list:

```
kosis_bewegung_01022018.txt
kosis_bewegung_01022018_fehlerliste.txt
kosis_bewegung_01022019.dat
kosis_bewegung_01022019_fehlerliste.dat
kosis_bestand_01022018.txt
kosis_bestand_01022018_fehlerliste.txt
kosis_bestand_01022019.dat
kosis_bestand_01022019_fehlerliste.dat
```

Now I also want to hide the files that contain "fehlerliste".

How do I have to adjust my filter for this?
Is it possible at all in one step?

Comment: Try selecting for a digit before the `.` - something like `pattern = "(bestand|bewegung).+\\d\\.(dat|txt)$"`

Comment: Thanks, that patterns fits my needs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R regexes support [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so the following should work:

```
dir(
  path = "m:/"
  ,pattern = "^(?!.*fehlerliste).*(?:bestand|bewegung).*\.(?:dat|txt)$"
)
```

Note the non-capturing groups I used to isolate the alternations. Otherwise, any filename that ends in `txt` would have matched, among others.

**Explanation:**

```
^                     # Start of string
(?!.*fehlerliste)     # Assert that "fehlerliste" doesn't occur in the string  
.*                    # match any number of characters
(?:bestand|bewegung)  # match "bestand" or "bewegung"
.*                    # match any number of characters
\.                    # match a dot
(?:dat|txt)           # match "dat" or "txt"
$                     # End of string
```

Comment: I've tried this pattern but R gives me an error for the pattern ```(?!.*fehlerliste)```. It says, that this pattern is invalid.

Comment: You need to set the parameter `perl = TRUE` when executing the regex, as in `grep("^(?!.*fehlerliste).*(?:bestand|bewegung).*\\.(?:dat|txt)$", subject, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Ah, that's it! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

1. Get the names of files with `bestand|bewegung\.dat|txt$`
2. Get rid of the files that contains `fehlerliste`

Using `dplyr` chaining it looks tidier:

```
library(dplyr)
files = grep(list.files(path = "m:/"),
             pattern = "bestand|bewegung\.dat|txt$", 
             value = TRUE)) %>%
        grep(list.files(path = "m:/"), 
             pattern = "fehlerliste", 
             invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
```

If you do not want to use `dplyr` then:

```
files = grep(list.files(path = "m:/"), 
             pattern = "bestand|bewegung\.dat|txt$",
             value = TRUE))
files = grep(list.files(path = "m:/"),
             pattern = "fehlerliste",
             invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))
```